# GAE: Best way to add (math) all values of an integer property from multiple instances

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have about 400+ model instances of a certain model ("Grade") in my datastore. They all have an integer property called "points" (points = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)) with different values.

What is the best way to get a cumulative sum of all the "points" values from each instance? Is there a way to do it without having to retrieve all the instances with Model.all()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could first do a GQL query to get keys of all entities that have the value of points > 0:

`SELECT __key__ FROM Grade WHERE points > 0`

This way you only pull up entities that you need, and ignore any entities that mathematically do not matter. Then, you can do a loop where you retrieve each entity you get a key for by doing db.get(Key) for each key and adding points up to a variable.

In GAE, queries that only get keys are more efficient and cost less: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Queries_on_Keys

Comment: But then you're calling an aditional function (db.get(Key)). Is this faster overall then just all()?

Comment: There's no point in doing a keys only query if you're just going to fetch the results anyway.